# Empty space below a page (Root div not covering html and body?)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, responsive-design, whitespace, vite

I am trying to use 2 images as background for the home page in my react,vite,ts project but when I resize the browser or view it in mobile there is a lot of empty space below the page.

[image: empty_space]

I have tried using every combination possible of height 100% 100vh etc.. in multiple spots/files.

***Link to the code:***
https://github.com/Antonio-Cristian/Vite-React-Ts-Goat-Farm

This Hero section is responsible for the empty space.

```
    <Container fluid style={{ margin: '0', padding: '0', overflowX: 'hidden'}}>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <div style={{ position: 'relative'}}>
                    <Image src={home_goat_farm2} alt="image1" fluid style={{ width: '100vw' }} />
                        <div style={{ 
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: '12.5%',
                            left: '50%',
                            transform: 'translate(-50%, -12.5%)',
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            color: 'white',
                            width: '100%'
                            }}>
                            <h1 style=*some styles*>Welcome to MyFarm</h1>
                            <p style=*some styles*>We grow organic produce for a healthier you</p>
                            <p style=*some styles*>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                        </div>
                         </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
            <Row>
                     <Col>
                         <Image src={goats} fluid style={{padding: 0 , margin: 0, border: 0, width: '100vw'}} />
                    </Col>
                 </Row>
    </div>
        </Container>
```

I also have this in my main.tsx file:

```
    const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
       html, body {
            background-color: lime;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
       }
    `
```

Comment: A link to the full project is welcome. But please add the essential parts in form of a [mre] as formatted text to your question.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? If the images can't cover the entire page, where do you expect the empty space to be?

Comment: I have edited the post to contain the home page code. @carlosV2 then isn't there another solution for the images to cover the page besides stretching the images vertically?

Comment: Image wise, there is lots of things you can do: you can stretch them, scale them, repeat them, etc. it really is up to you. However, if you don't want to transform your images, then something needs to fill this gap (or nothing if this is an accepted outcome). I suggest you try to draw what you would like the page to look like for different viewport configurations (vertical, horizontal, squared, rectangular, etc) and once you know what you want, then we can come back to the coding part. Alternatively, empty spaces are great to promote stuff or fill with explanations and text.